# From child class, call base class method while using child fields

Tags: c#, sql, oop, inheritance, .net-core

I have created a small ETL program with a single method that only takes a connection string for the source database and a connection string for a target database.

Basically, it has 5 steps:

Step 1. Select data from the source.
Step 2. Create a temporary table on the target.
Step 3. Load data from the source into the temporary on the target.
Step 4. Merge the data from temporary table into the actual target table.
Step 5. Drop the temporary table

This works great for a single transformation that needs to take place, but I have about 20 different ETL "jobs" that need to take place.

So instead of copying and pasting the same method verbatim 19 different times, I would like to define a base class that defines this single method one time, and then call this single method from each child class, with its own select, create, merge and drop statements.

Is this possible?

Base Class:

```
public class ETLBase
{

    private static string Select;
    private static string CreateTemp;
    private static string Merge;
    private static string CleanUp;
    private static string DestinationTable;


    public static void ExecuteJob(string sourceConnectionString, string destinationConnectionString)
    {
        using (OracleConnection sourceConnection = new OracleConnection(sourceConnectionString))
        {
            sourceConnection.Open();

            OracleCommand selectCommand = new OracleCommand(Select, sourceConnection);
            OracleDataReader reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();

            using (SqlConnection destinationConnection = new SqlConnection(destinationConnectionString))
            {
                destinationConnection.Open();

                SqlCommand createTempCommand = new SqlCommand(CreateTemp, destinationConnection);
                createTempCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                SqlCommand mergeCommand = new SqlCommand(Merge, destinationConnection);
                SqlCommand dropCommand = new SqlCommand(CleanUp, destinationConnection);

                using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(destinationConnection))
                {
                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = DestinationTable;

                    try
                    {
                        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
                        mergeCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        dropCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        reader.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Child Class:

```
public class ChildETL: ETLBase
{
    private static string Select = @"Select THIS DataStatement";
    private static string CreateTemp = @"CREATE TABLE Statement";
    private static string Merge = @"Merge Table statement";
    private static string CleanUp = "DROP TABLE Statement";
    private static string DestinationTable = "##TempTable";
}
```

And then execute it something like this, but where each child class uses its own defined fields, so it uses it's own SQL statements.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
            .Build();

        string schoolDBConnection = config["SchoolConnection"];
        string courseDBConnection = config["CourseConnection"];
        string teacherDBConnection = config["Connection"];

        ChildETLA.ExecuteJob(schoolDBConnection, courseDBConnection);
        ChildETLB.ExecuteJob(teacherDBConnection, courseDBConnection);

        //...and so on for each child ETL class

    }

}
```

Comment: Class inheritance is only possible for instance properties/methods. Maybe you can update the base class' method to receive Select, CreateTemp, etc as parameters instead, mark the method as protected, and create a new ExecuteJob method on each child class where you invoke the base class' method including the parameters. I hope this helps.

Comment: There's no real need to use inheritance in this case. Just add the command strings as method arguments and call the ExecuteJob() method from each of your jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to run "ExecuteJob()" polymorphically, which means behaviour of "ExeceuteJob" will be different based on source and destination connection string. You can't achieve polymorphism for static function or properties. First of all, you need to refactor it to instance method by taking out the "Static" keywords. Also, the behaviour of the base class is deciding by child classes so that nobody should be able to create an object of base class to make it an abstract class. Look at your code you have two behaviours one for school and another one for the teacher. So you have to create two different child classes which inherit the abstract base class. It is the responsibility of object creation to compose object with source and destination connection string so pass it to the constructor and set it while creating the object itself. Please find the refactored code,

```
public abstract class ETLBase
{
    private readonly string sourceConnectionString;
    private readonly string destinationConnectionString;

    protected virtual string Select { get; set; } = @"Select THIS DataStatement";
    protected virtual string CreateTemp { get; set; } = @"CREATE TABLE Statement";
    protected virtual string Merge { get; set; } = @"Merge Table statement";
    protected virtual string CleanUp { get; set; } = "DROP TABLE Statement";
    protected virtual string DestinationTable { get; set; } = "##TempTable";


    protected ETLBase(string sourceConnectionString, string destinationConnectionString)
    {
        this.sourceConnectionString = sourceConnectionString;
        this.destinationConnectionString = destinationConnectionString;
    }

    public void ExecuteJob()
    {
        using (OracleConnection sourceConnection = new OracleConnection(sourceConnectionString))
        {
            sourceConnection.Open();

            OracleCommand selectCommand = new OracleCommand(Select, sourceConnection);
            OracleDataReader reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();

            using (SqlConnection destinationConnection = new SqlConnection(destinationConnectionString))
            {
                destinationConnection.Open();

                SqlCommand createTempCommand = new SqlCommand(CreateTemp, destinationConnection);
                createTempCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                SqlCommand mergeCommand = new SqlCommand(Merge, destinationConnection);
                SqlCommand dropCommand = new SqlCommand(CleanUp, destinationConnection);

                using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(destinationConnection))
                {
                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = DestinationTable;

                    try
                    {
                        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
                        mergeCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        dropCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        reader.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And the child classes,

```
public class ChildETLSchool : ETLBase
    {
        public ChildETLSchool(string sourceConnectionString, string destinationConnectionString) 
            : base(sourceConnectionString, destinationConnectionString)
        {
            //Change values of below lines only if you want to override the values

            //Select = @"Select THIS DataStatement";
            //CreateTemp = @"CREATE TABLE Statement";
            //Merge = @"Merge Table statement";
            //CleanUp = "DROP TABLE Statement";
            //DestinationTable = "##TempTable";
        }

    }

    public class ChildETLTeacher : ETLBase
    {
        public ChildETLTeacher(string sourceConnectionString, string destinationConnectionString) 
            : base(sourceConnectionString, destinationConnectionString)
        {
            //Change values of below lines only if you want to override the values

            //Select = @"Select THIS DataStatement";
            //CreateTemp = @"CREATE TABLE Statement";
            //Merge = @"Merge Table statement";
            //CleanUp = "DROP TABLE Statement";
            //DestinationTable = "##TempTable";
        }

    }
```

And the object creation in main function,

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
        .Build();

        string schoolDBConnection = config["SchoolConnection"];
        string courseDBConnection = config["CourseConnection"];
        string teacherDBConnection = config["Connection"];

        var childETLSchool = new ChildETLSchool(schoolDBConnection, courseDBConnection);
        var childETLTeacher = new ChildETLTeacher(teacherDBConnection, courseDBConnection);

        childETLSchool.ExecuteJob();
        childETLTeacher.ExecuteJob();
    }
```